# overall (allfit) and incremental cumulative association (cumfit) - R Package 'dlnm'

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, dlm, distributed-lag

I am conducting research on the impact of between radiation dose and incidence of cancer in radiation epidemiology. To further explore this topic, I would like to utilize distributed lag non-linear models (DLNMs), which are commonly used in environmental epidemiology.

The `dlnm` package for implementing this model in the R software was developed by Antonio Gasparrini (reference: Gasparrini A. Distributed Lag Linear and Non-Linear Models in R: The Package dlnm. J Stat Softw. 2011;43(8):1-20).

I am relatively new to both R and the concept of DLNMs, essentially being a beginner.

The `matfit`, `allfit`, `cumfit` values were computed using the provided command. However, I observed that no value is generated at lag 0. As for the issue I encountered while generating the `crossbasis` and `crosspred` in our dataset, I would like to know if there are any solutions or possible mistakes that I might have overlooked.

```r
> cbdose <- crossbasis(dose, lag=22, 
                       argvar=list(fun="lin", intercept=FALSE), 
                       arglag=list(fun="ns", df=4, intercept=FALSE))
> glm <- glm(cancer ~ cbdose + sex + byr + st_dur, family="quasipoisson", 
             data=latency)
> pdose <- crosspred(cbdose, glm, cen=0)


> ns(dose, df=4)
                      1             2           3             4
      [1,] 3.442680e-01 -2.657878e-01 0.532098177 -0.2662476155
      [2,] 7.208440e-03 -2.087312e-01 0.417774229 -0.2090429877
      [3,] 6.624178e-01 -1.364256e-01 0.273776335 -0.1369902947
        :
        :
    [248,] 9.819764e-01  1.497426e-02 0.006003392 -0.0029540934
    [249,] 1.258991e-02 -2.451811e-01 0.490728420 -0.2455473025
    [250,] 2.317757e-01 -3.114461e-01 0.623404704 -0.3119349463
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1857506 rows ]
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
[1] 0.01125 0.09000 0.99000
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1]   0.00 603.59
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
Warning message:
In ns(dose, df = 4) :
  shoving 'interior' knots matching boundary knots to inside


> head(pdose[['matfit']])
   lag0       lag1       lag2       lag3       lag4       lag5        lag6        lag7        lag8        lag9      lag10      lag11       lag12       lag13
0     0 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
10    0 0.01409606 0.02586700 0.03298769 0.03313302 0.02397786 0.003389303 -0.02634476 -0.05851565 -0.08622244 -0.1025642 -0.1006402 -0.07803021 -0.05023819
20    0 0.02819212 0.05173399 0.06597538 0.06626604 0.04795572 0.006778606 -0.05268953 -0.11703129 -0.17244488 -0.2051285 -0.2012803 -0.15606042 -0.10047638
30    0 0.04228818 0.07760099 0.09896307 0.09939906 0.07193358 0.010167909 -0.07903429 -0.17554694 -0.25866732 -0.3076927 -0.3019205 -0.23409062 -0.15071457
40    0 0.05638424 0.10346798 0.13195076 0.13253207 0.09591144 0.013557212 -0.10537905 -0.23406258 -0.34488976 -0.4102570 -0.4025606 -0.31212083 -0.20095276
50    0 0.07048029 0.12933498 0.16493845 0.16566509 0.11988930 0.016946515 -0.13172382 -0.29257823 -0.43111220 -0.5128212 -0.5032008 -0.39015104 -0.25119095
         lag14       lag15      lag16      lag17      lag18      lag19     lag20     lag21     lag22
0   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
10 -0.03724882 -0.05904683 -0.1356169 -0.2862065 -0.5131034 -0.8016361 -1.136396 -1.501973 -1.882959
20 -0.07449765 -0.11809367 -0.2712339 -0.5724130 -1.0262068 -1.6032722 -2.272791 -3.003946 -3.765919
30 -0.11174647 -0.17714050 -0.4068508 -0.8586195 -1.5393103 -2.4049083 -3.409187 -4.505919 -5.648878
40 -0.14899530 -0.23618734 -0.5424678 -1.1448260 -2.0524137 -3.2065444 -4.545582 -6.007892 -7.531837
50 -0.18624412 -0.29523417 -0.6780847 -1.4310326 -2.5655171 -4.0081805 -5.681978 -7.509865 -9.414797


> head(pdose[['allfit']])
         0         10         20         30         40         50 
  0.000000  -6.723291 -13.446583 -20.169874 -26.893165 -33.616457 


> pdose2 <- crosspred(cbdose, glm, cen=0, cumul=TRUE)
> head(pdose2[['cumfit']])
   lag0       lag1       lag2       lag3      lag4      lag5      lag6      lag7       lag8        lag9      lag10      lag11      lag12      lag13      lag14
0     0 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
10    0 0.01409606 0.03996305 0.07295074 0.1060838 0.1300616 0.1334509 0.1071062 0.04859052 -0.03763192 -0.1401962 -0.2408363 -0.3188665 -0.3691047 -0.4063535
20    0 0.02819212 0.07992611 0.14590149 0.2121675 0.2601232 0.2669019 0.2142123 0.09718104 -0.07526384 -0.2803923 -0.4816726 -0.6377331 -0.7382094 -0.8127071
30    0 0.04228818 0.11988916 0.21885223 0.3182513 0.3901849 0.4003528 0.3213185 0.14577155 -0.11289577 -0.4205885 -0.7225090 -0.9565996 -1.1073142 -1.2190606
40    0 0.05638424 0.15985222 0.29180298 0.4243351 0.5202465 0.5338037 0.4284247 0.19436207 -0.15052769 -0.5607847 -0.9633453 -1.2754661 -1.4764189 -1.6254142
50    0 0.07048029 0.19981527 0.36475372 0.5304188 0.6503081 0.6672546 0.5355308 0.24295259 -0.18815961 -0.7009808 -1.2041816 -1.5943326 -1.8455236 -2.0317677
        lag15      lag16      lag17     lag18      lag19      lag20      lag21      lag22
0   0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
10 -0.4654004 -0.6010173 -0.8872238 -1.400327  -2.201963  -3.338359  -4.840332  -6.723291
20 -0.9308008 -1.2020346 -1.7744477 -2.800655  -4.403927  -6.676718  -9.680664 -13.446583
30 -1.3962011 -1.8030520 -2.6616715 -4.200982  -6.605890 -10.015077 -14.520996 -20.169874
40 -1.8616015 -2.4040693 -3.5488953 -5.601309  -8.807853 -13.353436 -19.361328 -26.893165
50 -2.3270019 -3.0050866 -4.4361192 -7.001636 -11.009817 -16.691795 -24.201660 -33.616457
```